# applicable_formats for only the user 'My home'

Tags: moodle

What needs to be in the array in the `applicable_formats()` function so it only is available on the `My home` page of the user? I've set `my-index` to true.

acces.php

```
<?php
$capabilities = array(

'block/groups:myaddinstance' => array(
    'captype' => 'write',
    'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_SYSTEM,
    'archetypes' => array(
        'user' => CAP_ALLOW
    ),

    'clonepermissionsfrom' => 'moodle/my:manageblocks'
),

'block/groups:addinstance' => array(
    'riskbitmask' => RISK_SPAM | RISK_XSS,

    'captype' => 'write',
    'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_BLOCK,
    'archetypes' => array(
        'editingteacher' => CAP_ALLOW,
        'manager' => CAP_ALLOW
    ),

    'clonepermissionsfrom' => 'moodle/site:manageblocks'
),
);
```

I've copied access.php from the blocks tutorial and only changed the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE - it should be just 'my' rather than 'my-index'.

Also just for completeness, you might want to add all = false

```
public function applicable_formats() {
    return array('all' => false, my' => true);
}
```

Comment: I have exactly that but it doesn't work, this should work for the page at `my-ip/moodle/my/index.php` right?

Comment: Im not able to add it anywhere, not even the user my home page, it doesnt show up in the 'add block' list

Comment: Did the block install? It should be listed under site admin -> plugins -> manage plugins. If it is then maybe check the capabilities in /blocks/yourblock/db/access.php

Comment: The block installed, added access.php so you can see

Comment: Any clue? got a repo [here](https://github.com/zaans2/JELOGroups) so you can see for yourself

Comment: yep, it should be my rather than my-index - updated the answer